# Need help understanding Node asynchronous.

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

So I am a beginner in learning Node and trying to understand the asynchronous part of it. The following code in `readIn` should wait for `readFile` to finish and then execute `whenDone` to update the `arr` variable, but whatever value I pass in as it always shows that the arr is empty. I don't think the `arr` was ever mutated or the function `whenDone` never waited for the `readFile` to finish.

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong or misunderstood?

Thank you

```
var fs = require('fs');
var arr = [];

function readIn(callback){
    fs.readFile(process.argv[2],'utf8',function whenDone(err, fileContent){

        arr = fileContent.split('\n');
        callback();
    })
}

var result = arr.length -1

function printOut(){
    console.log(result);
}

readIn(printOut);
```

Comment: You define the arr, then the function readIn.
Then you define a var result which gets equal to -1 because the length is 0 at the time. Then you define the print function and call the readIn function which will print -1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `readFile` function is asynchronous so it returns control to the caller.
You should rewrite like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');


function readIn(callback){
    fs.readFile(process.argv[2],'utf8',function whenDone(err, fileContent){
        var arr = fileContent.split('\n');
        callback(arr);
    })
}


function printOut(arr){
    console.log(arr);
}

readIn(printOut);
```